# Will more wifi routers make the wifi "better"

Tags: wireless-router

I recently got a desktop pc and our family's WiFi has gotten a lot worse. They blame it on me because they say I'm using all of the network "space". (They call me star killer base. Because I suck all of the energy from the sun.) Anyway, I was thinking of purchasing another router for my computer. But I didn't know if it would make a difference to the WiFi.

Comment: It depends what you're doing with your computer when it's connected to the wireless/Internet activities...

Comment: Test with a wired machine. If the wired machine shows poor Internet performance as well, then the issue has nothing to do with the WiFi.

Comment: Some times using different types of wifi can cause interference.  The 802.11 spec has a.b.c.g.n,ac, and new types are being invented.  This type can usually be adjusted using the software that came with your wifi adapter.  Assuming your desktop is on the wifi also, see if it is set for whatever the other users in the house are using.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to make a bet based on the information provided, the answer is probably no, it will not help. Here is why:

1) Assuming your users are not particularly distant from the access point, and there are not lots of thing which could be interfering, you should get a reasonable signal for most things.

2) If things worked fine until you got a desktop (which I assume is NOT on the wireless network, it is wired, correct?) then it is highly unlikely the wireless would suddenly get worse.

3) Internet speed is determined by your ISP plan, not # of routers or potential throughput of routers most of the time. This means if you have a 10 or 20mbps connection with your ISP (Cox, Comcast, ATT, etc) that, no matter what your routers can do, you can't exceed that number (or at least not by much).

So what is likely happening is that your desktop is using some/the majority of your ISP provided bandwidth and it is causing other connections to become slow, wait, or have loss. A good way to test this would be to wait until they are having an issue and then temporarily disconnecting your desktop from the network. If their issues improve over the next minute or so, it is likely programs/updates/downloads, etc. on your desktop saturating your link.

The times when having more wifi routers makes the wifi better are typically when you have 'poor signal' areas, needs to accommodate larger numbers of clients, or have large amounts of internal (inside your network) traffic happening (moving files (like backups) between computers on your network on the wifi for a large percentage of the time. Also, you would typically want a more 'enterprise' geared access point/controller to help deliver these benefits, not consumer grade hardware in most cases - they will facilitate load balancing, handing off connections between APs, firewall/QOS/Security features, and so on.

Please provide more information if you want a more thorough answer and remember to comment/mark as answer on answers/comments which provide the information you need. Welcome to SuperUser!